# Save changes to object not part of the current db context

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a web service to get an object, such as

```
public Blah GetBlah(int blahID) {
   var db = new BlahContext...
}
```

and another web service

```
public UpdateBlah(int blahID) {
    var db = new BlahContext...
    var blah = GetBLah(blahID);
    blah.someVariable = false;
    ... // how do I save this object?
}
```

But I don't think I can do SubmitChanges as the object was not created in the same context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `UpdateBlah` you need to pass the object as parameter so you can have the data to update.

Then you can choose two alternatives:

### 1. Mapping (manual or auto)

```
public UpdateBlah(object blahUpdated) {
    var db = new BlahContext...
    var blah = GetBLah(blahID);
    // manually mapping
    blah.someVariable = blahUpdated.someVariable;
    // or using some kind to automapper (automapper.codeplex.com)
    ... 
    db.SubmitChanges()
}
```

### 2. Attach

You can `attach` the object to the new datacontext

```
public UpdateBlah(object blahUpdated) {
    var db = new BlahContext...
    db.blahs.Attach(blahUpdated);
    db.SubmitChanges()
}
```